# Qt creator with several projects: avoid each project "reviewing"

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I currently have a .pro of subprojects template. This .pro file references a lot of other .pro files, each one being a project itself. It compiles, builds and runs.

The problem is that each time I want to run my program, Qt Creator (or perhaps it's make itselfs) checks all projects' status or something like that. For each project it shows the following:

```
cd A_PROJECT_DIRECTORY && ( test -e Makefile ||
/opt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake A_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/PROJECT_FILE.pro
-spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ) && /usr/bin/make -f Makefile 
    make[1]: Entering directory `A_PROJECT_DIRECTORY'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `A_PROJECT_DIRECTORY'
```

It takes very little time for each one of those operations but there are so many projects that at the end it has a sensible impact in the edit + build + test workflow.

So, the question is: is there any way to skip those make "tests" or whatever are they and launch immediatly the executable after it has been built? Or some other way to speed up this process?

All the above is in Linux environment.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? I have the same issue but it feel like it is worse on Windows compared to Linux for the same project

Comment: I modified the question. All that is in Linux, I didn't try it in Windows.